# How to make a watcher run only once per digest cycle, no matter how many times the property changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function `$scope.render()` which uses the value `$scope.myProperty` to render a chart. If `myProperty` changes during a digest cycle, I want to call `$scope.render()` at the end of the digest cycle, *at most once per digest cycle*.

```
$scope.$watch('myProperty', function(v, vold) {
    if ($scope.switch) {
        $scope.myProperty ++;
        $scope.switch = false;
    }

    $scope.render();
});
```

In this case, if `$scope.switch`, then `$scope.render()` will be called twice. How can I only call it once?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is Angular's handy [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service.

```
var dirty = false;
$scope.$watch('myProperty', function(v, vold) {
    if ($scope.switch) {
        $scope.myProperty ++;
        $scope.switch = false;
    }

    dirty = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        if (dirty) {
            $scope.render();
            dirty = false;
        }
    });
});
```

So now, `$scope.render` will be called whenever `myProperty` changes, and it will be called *exactly once* at the end of the digest cycle, no matter how many times `myProperty` changes.

Comment: did you test this? it just seems that the dirty should be conditionally set or set above the prop change, or is this actually ok and i'm mis-reading it?

Comment: When this executes, (1) the watcher will be called twice and will set `dirty=true` twice. Then, (2) after the digest cycle is done, the timeout function is called twice. The first call calls `render` and sets the dirty flag to false, and then the second call sees the dirty flag is false and does nothing.

Comment: You could just as easily extract the `if (dirty)` before the `$timeout` and prevent registering the function repeatedly.  (You also have to change the logic a little, though; the condition becomes
    if (!dirty) {
      dirty = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        /* do what you want*/
        dirty = false; 
      });
    }
// end code sample)